# activity class intent into a specific fragment (fragment in a navigation drawer)

Tags: android, android-fragments

I was trying to make an intent from activity to a specific fragment from a navigation drawer. i was try the fragment transaction but it is not working on me.

This is my code:

My Activity (On-click activity going to a specific Fragment from a navigation drawer):

```
 private void checkCarts() {
        checkCart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                fragment=new EppViewCartV2();
                if (fragment != null) {
                    FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    ft.replace(R.id.frams, fragment);
                    ft.commit();
                }



            }
        });
    }
```

[Error code upon logcat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ANv6s.png)

```
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uuFMq.png
```

[my error (upon using getFragmentManager)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ANv6s.png)

[my farams (framelayout):](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UOQJS.png)

this is my basic activity ():
-this is the appbar activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ItemViewProducts.EppItemPreviewPhone">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="#f2f2f2"
        app:elevation="0dp"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar.AppBarOverlay">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/view_back"
            android:layout_width="24dp"
            android:layout_height="24dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:src="@drawable/arrow_back"/>


            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/qqt"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/view_cart2"
                android:layout_width="26dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_height="26dp"
                android:src="@drawable/shopping"/>
            </RelativeLayout>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="20dp"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                android:id="@+id/badge_notification"
                android:layout_alignRight="@id/qqt"
                android:background="@drawable/item_status"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:text="12"
                android:textColor="#fff"
                android:padding="3dp"
                android:textSize="10sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                ></TextView>

        </RelativeLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_epp_item_preview_phone" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fbutton_add_to_cart"
        app:rippleColor="@null"
        app:backgroundTint="@null"
        app:maxImageSize="30dp"
        android:scaleType="center"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:backgroundTint="#b578ff"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/cart_big"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end" />


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

the content Activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#f2f2f2"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context=".ItemViewProducts.EppItemPreviewPhone"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_epp_item_preview_phone">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="410dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/radius_all"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/relativeLayout4"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="240dp">

            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/viewPager2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/radius_all"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:layout_height="240dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="25dp"
                android:layout_height="25dp"
                android:id="@+id/rightright"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:src="@drawable/leftleft"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp">
            </ImageView>

            <ImageView
            android:layout_width="25dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:id="@+id/leftleft"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:src="@drawable/rightright"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp">
            </ImageView>


        </RelativeLayout>


        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="280dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="190dp"
            android:text="Harman Karton - AURA STUDIO 2"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:id="@+id/view_subject"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="245dp"
            android:id="@+id/view_on_hand"
            android:text="Available(150)"
            android:textSize="11dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="238dp"
            android:text="P 14,999.00"
            android:id="@+id/view_new_price"
            android:textColor="#f24800"
            android:textSize="21dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="110dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="270dp"
            android:text="P 145,999.00"
            android:id="@+id/view_srp"
            android:textSize="16dp" />


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="150dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="270dp"
            android:text=" - 50%"
            android:id="@+id/view_discount"
            android:textColor="#af0000"
            android:textSize="17dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="275dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="110dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:text="x"
            android:textSize="12dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:id="@+id/view_btn_less"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="273dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="85dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:src="@drawable/left_arrow" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="273dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="53dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:text="1"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:id="@+id/view_count"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textSize="14dp" />


        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:id="@+id/view_btn_add"
            android:layout_marginTop="273dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:src="@drawable/right_arrow"
            android:textSize="17dp" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="300dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:background="#bababa"
            android:src="@drawable/right_arrow"
            android:textSize="17dp" />


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="45dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="310dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="150dp"
            android:text="Total"
            android:textSize="15dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="140dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="305dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:text="P 14,999.00"
            android:id="@+id/view_total"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        </RelativeLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout4"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="420dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/radius_all"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/relativeLayout3"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/relativeLayout2">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
            android:text="Color Variation"
            android:textSize="12dp" />


        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="190dp"
            android:id="@+id/color5"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"

            android:textSize="17dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="150dp"
            android:id="@+id/color4"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"

            android:textSize="17dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:id="@+id/color3"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="110dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"

            android:textSize="17dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="70dp"
            android:id="@+id/color2"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"

            android:textSize="17dp" />

        <ImageView
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:id="@+id/color1"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"

        android:textSize="17dp" />




    </RelativeLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="478dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:text="Product description"
            android:textSize="14dp"/>




        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/radius_all"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:id="@+id/view_product_description"
            android:text=" \n \n
            - Enter your model number \n  \n
            - Compatible with all devices with a stereo minijack output \n \n
            - Outstanding bass performance \n \n
            - Touch volume and mute controls \n \n
            - Subwoofer volume control \n \n"
            android:textSize="11dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:text="Product specification"
            android:textSize="14dp"/>


            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/radius_all"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:id="@+id/view_product_specification"
                android:text=" \n \n
            - Enter your model number \n  \n
            - Compatible with all devices with a stereo minijack output \n \n
            - Outstanding bass performance \n \n
            - Touch volume and mute controls \n \n
            - Subwoofer volume control \n \n"
                android:textSize="11dp" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:text="Other Products"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>


            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/view_product_other_items"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">
            </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
        </LinearLayout>




        </LinearLayout>



    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: The error says you have no view `R.id.frams` in your layout. Can you post the layout you're using in your activity?

Comment: i have but its blank since i was used for catch data only

Comment: You've posted the `content_epp_drawer.xml` file - how is that related to your activity?

Comment: that was my navigation drawer content

Comment: you can see my answer now how i solve the problem sir :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was figure it out my answer.. 
 instead of using the fragment transaction , i use intent

first, i was intent my activity to my navigation drawer and add a static String data (catch data)

my Activity:

```
 private void checkCarts() {
        checkCart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

               Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),EppDrawer.class);
               openSisame="okay";
               startActivity(i);



            }
        });
    }
```

and in my drawer, ive set a try catch hat if it is okay, it will go to a fragment that ive like to display, and if it is not i will display my main page.
 like this one:

```
try{
        if(EppItemPreviewPhone.openSisame.equals("okay")){
            displaySelectedScreen(2131296453);

        }
    }catch (Exception e){
        Toast.makeText(this, "NONE", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        fragment=new EppMainFragment();
        if (fragment != null) {
            FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            ft.replace(R.id.frams, fragment);
            ft.commit();
        }

    }

  private void displaySelectedScreen(int itemId) {


    //initializing the fragment object which is selected
    switch (itemId) {
        case R.id.nav_home:
            fragment = new EppMainFragment();
            break;

        case R.id.nav_my_account:
            fragment = new EppMyAccount();
            break;
        case R.id.nav_view_cart:
            fragment = new EppViewCartV2();
            break;

        case R.id.nav_order:
            fragment = new EppOrderHistory();
            break;
        case R.id.nav_find:
            fragment = new EppFindProduct();
            break;
        case R.id.nav_about:
            fragment = new AboutFragment();
            break;
    }

    //replacing the fragment
    if (fragment != null) {
        FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.frams, fragment);
        ft.commit();
    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
}
```

hence: this value (2131296453) is a value from the id of my fragment.
thank you guys for your answers even it is solve my code but you give me a logic to solve it :)

Answer (score 0):

When you are using `android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager` then you should use `getSupportFragmentManager()` and if you are using `android.app.FragmentManager` then use `getFragmentManager()`.

```
 private void checkCarts() {
        checkCart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                fragment=new EppViewCartV2();
                if (fragment != null) {
                    FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    ft.replace(R.id.frams, fragment);
                    ft.commit();
                }



            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: ive try this one but i caught an error. I will add to my question whats the detailed error :)

Comment: You'd get an entirely different compile time error if this was the problem, not a runtime error, so this isn't at all related to the issue.

Comment: upon my appbar activity, the Imageview with the id (@+id/view_cart2)  that was my button that i was fixing...

Comment: you can see my answer now how i solve the problem sir :)

Answer (score 0):

When you say `ft.replace(R.id.frams, fragment);`, you are saying "put `fragment` into the container specified by `R.id.frams`.

That means that a layout with the id `R.id.frams` must be in your layout, in this case - in your activity's layout (since you're calling `getSupportFragmentManager()` and getting the activity's `FragmentManager`).

You need to change your activity's layout to include that layout.

Comment: yeah, maybe i will tru to create fragment that will be imbedded to my app, since i didn't call the my existing fragment... will try your idea sir thanks.

Comment: i try recreating sample fragment layout bit it is the same error ive got. maybe it is possible to solvew this one since i was on a  activity and trying to reach the specific page or fragment from the navigation drawer fragments.

Comment: Can you add your activity's layout xml to your question?

Comment: okay sir, also , it was basic activity. let me add for a while sir :)

Comment: So where in that layout do you want the Fragment you're hoping to add to appear? That's kind of the whole point: fragments get added to a container. That container needs to already exist in your activity's layout.

Comment: yeah, you get my point sir.. also, if ever it is possible, i will like  also attach the navigation drawer upon calling this fragments.. (sorry, for my architecture of development, totally it sucks. (fragment /activity instead of doing fragments only) if i cant figure out this one, maybe i will migrate my layouts from activity to fgragments :)

Comment: i found my answer sir . :)

Comment: Yeah, looks like you'll need to do some significant reorganizing to get things working. Best of luck! You might consider looking at the [Migrate to the Navigation Component](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-migrate) documentation, which starts from having everything in your activity and gives you step by step instructions for moving that into Fragments (and then tying those Fragments together via the Navigation Architecture Component).

Comment: you can see my answer now how i solve the problem  sir :)